# CondaMemoryError: The conda process ran out of memory

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda, anaconda3

I installed conda through miniforge : https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge

My environment was working normally until recently where any conda command results in:

```html
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaMemoryError: The conda process ran out of memory. Increase system memory and/or try again.
```

I have a MacBook Pro 13-inch, M1 2020 with 16 GB. It always has at least 6GB free memory

I don't understand why conda complains about lack of memory here

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 uninstall pyOpenSSl
```

This command solved my problem.
I hope I can help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33860912)

Answer (score -2):

Run:

```
conda update conda -c conda-canary
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30551333)

Comment: @FlavianHautbois: It _does_ offer an answer. Though it's _unclear_ how it would solve the original problem. The author should [edit] it to include more explanation.

Comment: Thank you  Jeremy Caney. I met same issue so I advise the author try this code.Thx